# Debian installer - no network hardware detected (Gigabyte B550 ITX)

Tags: linux, debian, networking, firmware

I'm a beginner when it comes to linux troubleshooting so bear with me.
I'm trying to install Debian on new hardware and I've run into an issue I haven't encountered with my previous two computers. The installer won't detect either the wired/wireless network hardware and I can't seem to find a solution. There are no issues in Windows 10 so it definitely isn't a hardware problem.

I'm using the [Gigabyte B550 ITX](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX-rev-10/sp#sp)

Network hardware:

- Realtek 2.5GbE LAN chip (2.5 Gbit/1 Gbit/100 Mbit)
- Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200

I've tried:

1. the basic net installer
2. the net installer with the unpacked tarball for the [realtek](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software) and [intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html) drivers in the firmware folder
3. the full installer that includes [non-free firmware](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/10.9.0+nonfree/)

I'm at a loss as to what to try next. Any help getting this machine up and running would be greatly appreciated, thanks for your time.

---

Edit:
So while I was looking around I saw that there will apparently be better hardware compatibility with the newer kernel that will be shipping with Debian 11. I gave the installer a chance, this time it recognized that my motherboard's network hardware needed non-free firmware. (it spit out quite the list but the net installer can't download it)

I'm not to keen on running a potentially unstable OS but I imagine it can't be worse than W10... any thoughts on how I should proceed?

Comment: Use USB-tethering during the install, and install the kernel from backports, and the firmwares from "non-free".

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?
So I should be able to tether from my phone which is connected to wifi? Install kernel from backports? I'm guessing this is done via command line.

Comment: Debian 10 uses a 4.19 kernel but there are backports of the 5.10 kernel/firmware which can be installed. There is no guarantee that this will fix your networking. I've been using `5.10.0-0.bpo.5-amd64` for the last few months on the Debian version of Mint [LMDE] and it appears to be completely stable.

Comment: I managed to get the debian 11 (testing) installer to recognize the intel wireless adapter using a second USB, but now I've run into another problem.

I'm getting this error message after using my network passphrase:
"Failure of key exchange and association"

Does anyone have an explanation/fix for this error?