# Debian Installer: "Failure of key exchange and association" when attempting wifi connection

Tags: wifi

I previously posted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/651340/debian-installer-no-network-hardware-detected-gigabyte-b550-itx) seeking advice on how to get Debian installed on my PC. I managed to get the debian 11 (testing) installer to recognize the intel wireless adapter using a secondary USB drive with non-free firmware, but now I've run into another problem.

I'm getting this error message after using my network passphrase: "Failure of key exchange and association" Does anyone have an explanation/fix for this error? The network/passphrase works on every other device I own.

Comment: Having the same problem.. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 10):

Select `Enter ESSID manually` from the list and enter the name of your wifi.

I was able to work around the problem by entering my ESSID manually, though it is listed after the installer scanned for available ESSIDs.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've no clue why, but it worked here as well (Thinkpad X1 Carbon 7th gen)

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: Worked for me also.

Comment: Didn’t work for me

Comment: This worked for me !

Comment: this worked for me. is this a trailing space issue with the installer? it looks exactly the same as what I entered

Comment: work for me too!!

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable the 5 GHz frequency band in my access point. Although my Intel wireless chip is capable of 5 GHz. SSIDs were found but key exchange failed before the change.